# Why og image is not showing on Facebook?

Tags: facebook, meta

I am having a problem when I try to use the `og:image` it is not showing when I share the link on Facebook but it is visible on WhatsApp any help please I really need this to work its urgent and sorry but I am not an expert and I need help thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Facebook has its own debugging online tool in order to fix these kind of issues so basically all you need is to go to [Facebook debug tool](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/) and enter the URL and press debug in this way Facebook will refresh the cache stored and will definitely show the og image.